# Task "serve" not found

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

I'm a newbie in Angular and I've cloned a repo (angular-slider). My problem is that when I type in console grunt serve it says Warning: Task "serve" not found. Use --force to continue. I've been searching through Internet and I've tried everything. I don't know which is the origin of my problem. If I type node -v the console gives me this v0.10.33 and if I type npm -v I get this 2.11.2 I already have a Gruntfile.js and a package.json and bower.json at the same level folder that my root project directory. Any help would be appreciated.

Edited:

This is my Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt){
'use strict';

// Project configuration.
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    srcFiles: [
        'src/rangeInputSupported.js',
        'src/angular-slider.js'
    ],
    concat: {
        prod: {
            src: ['<%= srcFiles %>'],
            dest: 'build/<%= pkg.name %>.js'
        }
    },
    uglify: {
        options: {
            banner: '/*\n <%= pkg.name %> v<%= pkg.version %> \n (c) 2013-2014 Venturocket, Inc. http://github.com/Venturocket \n License: MIT \n*/\n'
        },
        build: {
            src: ['<%= srcFiles %>'],
            dest: 'build/<%= pkg.name %>.min.js'
        }
    },
    jshint: {
        options: {
            jshintrc: true,
            reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
        },
        all: {
            src: [
                'Gruntfile.js',
                'karma.conf.js',
                'src/**/*.js',
                'test/**/*.js'
            ],
            options: {
                force: true
            }
        }
    }
});

// Load the plugin that provides the "uglify" task.
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');

// Default task(s).
grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint:all', 'uglify', 'concat:prod']);

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');

};
```

And my bower.json looks like this:

```
{
"name": "angular-slider",
"version": "0.3.2",
"main": "./build/angular-slider.js",
"ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "components",
    "lib",
    "src",
    "test",
    ".g*",
    ".editorconfig",
    ".jshintrc",
    ".travis.yml",
    "Gruntfile.js",
    "karma.conf.js",
    "*.html"
],
"dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.2",
    "angular-touch": "~1.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "*",
    "angular-scenario": "*"
},
"resolutions": {
    "angular": "v1.2.16"
}
}
```

Comment: run grunt --help you will see the available tasks. It's possible that it's call server.

Comment: If I type grunt --help the console tells me that as available tasks I just have uglify, jshint, default and concat. How can I include de serve task ??

Answer (score 4):

This usually appears if you don't have grunt installed. Also you should install bower if you don't have it.

Try to install grunt like so : `npm install -g grunt-cli` . Also you should run in you're project file `npm install && bower install` to download all the dependencies that you need in you're project. I hope it helped.

Comment: When I do npm install && bower install the console ask me to choose a version for angular, but I'm not sure which one I should choose => bower resolution    Unsuitable resolution declared for angular: v1.2.16 Unable to find a suitable version for angular, please choose one: 1) angular#~1.2 which resolved to 1.2.28 and is required by angular-slider 2) angular#1.2.28 which resolved to 1.2.28 and is required by angular-touch#1.2.28 3) angular#1.4.1 which resolved to 1.4.1 and is required by angular-mocks#1.4.1, angular-scenario#1.4.1 Prefix the choice with ! to persist it to bower.json ? Answer:

Comment: Near each version it says which component requires that version. You need to choose the version that requires your angular module. If you're angular module is named "moduleX", you will see there version : angular 1.4.x (x = any number or something) - "moduleX"

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have 'serve' registeredTask in your gruntFile.js .

If it is there then probably grunt is not installed on your system. Install grunt-cli from npm and also the bower on your system. So that you have node_modules in your folder structure.

Use the following commands :

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
npm install --save
bower install --save
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Vaibhav I've edited my question to show you my gruntfile.js . I've seen that I  have grunt.registeredTask but there's no serve inside => grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint:all', 'uglify', 'concat:prod']); May be I have to put 'serve' inside the parameters??

Comment: Yes, there has to be task something like the following :
grunt.registerTask('serve', ['jshint:all', 'uglify', 'concat:prod']);

Comment: nothing. When I type grunt serve the console gives me back this Running "jshint:all" (jshint) task
src/angular-slider.js
  line 802  col 42  'offsetFromValue' is defined but never used.

✖ 1 problem
Running "uglify:build" (uglify) task
File "build/angular-slider.min.js" created.

Running "concat:prod" (concat) task
File build/angular-slider.js created.

Done, without errors. But it does nothing...it doesn't tell me which port to use or open a browser

Answer (score 0):

Just do

`grunt`

...on its own. This runs the 'default' task

We can see toward the bottom of your GruntFile.js that you have a definition of the 'default' task

`grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint:all', 'uglify', 'concat:prod']);`

...which I think will be the one to start up the server

I had thought that "serve" was a standard task name (also with alias "server") but I'm seeing gruntfiles where these are not defined, and where the "default" (just the `grunt` command on its own) starts the server. Maybe this is a standard thing with Angular(?)